# Is Stack OverFlow Error possible in finite recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a recursive method that I am fairly certain is finite. However, when I run it I receive a stack overflow error. Is there another possible way to get stack overflow that I happen to be doing or what is wrong with the method?

```
public static void solve(int row, int column){
    if (row<=8){
        if (column>8){
            solve(row+1, 0);
        }
        if (row<=8 && column<=8 && (Rows[row][column]==0)){
            for (int a = 1; a<=9;a++){
                if (check(row, column, a)==false&&Rows[row][column]!=a){
                    Rows[row][column]=a;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        solve(row, column+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Is Stack OverFlow Error possible in finite recursion?* **Yes**. See also the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

Comment: Yes it is quite possible in "finite" recursion -- since it is easy to write a program that does finite recursion, but will run out of most common sizes of stack memory, a very **finite** resource.

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently in a hurry, so I can't write an answer about your problem, but you want `if (column>8) solve(row+1, 0); else solve(row, column+1);`. The single line `solve(row, column+1);` in your code should only be used if `column>8` is false.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a bug in your code, and that your method is in fact infinitely recurring.

Comment: @Tom Thanks so Much. Changing that reduced the memory and it works fine now.

Comment: Can you overflow a cup with a finite amount of water?

Answer (score 2):

Stack size in JVM is limited so it is possible to get StackOverflow with finite recursion or even without any recursion.

You can increase JVM stack size using `-Xss` option:

```
java -Xss16M YouMainClass
```